# during java debugging in eclipse IDE, same variable displayed differently with different icon in "expression view"

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I'm learning java debugging using eclipse IDE, somehow I have added the same variable to the "expression view" twice, but the two instance of the same variable is displayed differently with different icon (first variable is displayed with "x+y=?" icon and second is displayed with a magnifying glass icon). So I was just wondering what is the difference between them? If there is any.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one (with a x+y=? icon) is a **watch expression**. Eclipse will evaluate this expression when it reaches the code where this expression appears (or when all the required expressions became available). Otherwise you will see `<error(s)_during_the_evaluation>`.

The second one is an **inspect variable**. This is just a variable from the code, which value will change during the execution.

Watch expression can be not only a variable. You can write any expression that you want to check during execution. E.g. you have two variables `int x` and `int y` so you can add watch expressions like `"x+y"` and get a sum once these variables get values. You can add as many expressions as you want: `"x*y"`, `"x/y"` or `"(x*y)/2"` etc.

Comment: thank you so much for the answer! it is really detailed and easy to understand.